# FireBreath WlanOpenHandle Error 1062 "The service has not been started"

Tags: c++, windows, firebreath

In my FireBreath plugin I am trying to determine Wifi SSID and/or scan for visible Wifi access points.

In the Windows portion of the code this entails starting with the following:

```
dwResult = WlanOpenHandle(dwMaxClient, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
```

Unfortunately, `dwResult` is always returning: 1062, which translates to "*The service has not been started*" (via `FormatMessage()`).

I have tried running in the main thread as well as in a boost thread started as follows:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&LaasTechAPI::doSomethingTimeConsuming_thread, this, num, callback));
```

The error 1062 is the same regardless.

*(Incidentally, I implemented the thread methodology because a. Internet search indicates some sort of an ATL/MTL 'apartment' threading issue and b. Wifi scan is known to be an inherently slow asynchronous endeavor, so threading seemed necessary all along)*

**Can anyone tell me how to solve this WlanOpenHandle error 1062 issue?**

---

*Secondary*:

- Can you tell me a more reliable way to scan for Wifi SSID, BSSID,
  and signal strengths of the local access points in Windows?
- I must also gather Wifi info for OS X. So, if you know of a Mac or
  multi-platform solution for the Wifi scan, please share.

Thank you!

Comment: Check the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759(v=vs.85).aspx) - the WZC service should be running.

Comment: You haven't specified which browser you're in, but note that in IE w/ UAC enabled on windows Vista or later you may not be able to access these APIs due to being in protected mode (low integrity process mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to Start Windows Zero Configuration Service (WZC)

This will solve Windows Error 1062: "The service has not been started".

I think you should look more closely at @Georg's comment and verify that WZC is started. Here is the relevant text from the remarks section at his link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759(v=vs.85).aspx

> WlanOpenHandle will return an error message if the Wireless Zero
>   Configuration (WZC) service has not been started or if the WZC service
>   is not responsive.

Enable the services in a Windows Command Prompt (DOS):

```
> net start wzcsvc
```

Or, type:

```
> sc config wzcsvc start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto>
```

Help message:

```
> sc config /?
```

Or, open the Services app:

```
> services.msc
```

Comment: There's no wzcsvc service on Windows 10.